# Using ArcGIS Online Dashboard Map Zoom

Tags: arcgis-online, zoom, dashboard

I have a dashboard with a few different elements on it. The Map element and the List element are connected to each other and I have them set up that when you click on a feature name from the List element it is supposed to zoom into the feature on the map. However, when I click on the feature name from the list it looks like it zooms into the correct location, but the basemap and the feature fail to load/disappear because all you see is a blank, white screen instead of the feature or the basemap.

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Since the Zoom action on the Map element of a Dashboard cannot be pre-configured to a default zoom level in response to a List selection, I suggest a bummer of a work-around:

- Create a buffer layer of the point elements in your Operational Layer
- Add that layer to your Dashboard, but keep it turned off
- Keep the point features turned on and visible
- Connect the List to the buffer layer instead of the point layer
- Configure the List Action to Zoom to the Buffer Feature rather than the point feature

I know, what a cludge, but until the Zoom action allows a default maximum zoom, we will all continue to zoom into points at too tight a zoom level to see on the Dashboard.

Comment: @mv9916 did this work for you? If so then please checkmark the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can edit the dashboards json (pointZoomScale) to the wanted zoom scale in ago-assistant. Check out: https://youtu.be/Ou3mokGsLGA?si=SGPhu2bz6yBpLQ5a&t=214

Comment: This is the proper way to do this.